# How do I integrate a Media library to Image Field?

Tags: 8, media

I have a image upload element field in my content type. I need to open a media library when I click on browse. My expectation is to select an image which I have already uploaded before. So I don't have to upload the same image again and again.

I've searched but I couldn't find a module for media library in Drupal 8. They are saying it is in the core of Drupal 8. I couldn't find it too. Is there an easy way to do this? Simply what I wanted is a library like in the image.(this is the media library in wordpress)

[image: This is the media library in wordpress.]

Comment: This looks so wordpress to me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [entity_browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser).

Setup isn't that easy, so you may want to use an existing browser like [media_entity_browser](http://media_entity_browser) as a starting point.

The media library as shown in your image can be found at `admin/content/media`, but it's not that helpful when it comes to reusing images on a node.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser 
and its require modules and libraries.

--> Add image field inside any content type and select widget type = **Entity Browser**

you can also add this inside the editor to enable the button from configuration